# javascript + define dates for each quarter

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown on my page named Quarter which has following values -

```
Quarter 1
Quarter 2
Quarter 3
Quarter 4
```

Also i have another field named Year with Year values - 2015,2016,2-17,2-18,2019,2020

I want to define the values for each quarter in my javascript code like

```
if(quarter = "quarter 1")
{
  startdate = 2017-01-01;enddate = 2017-01-31
}
```

And so on for other quarters as well.

I would like to ask if there is built-in functionality to get the startdate and enddate for each quarter and i will append the year field value to it.so that it does not remain static.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the start of quarter 1?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Jan first

Comment: There is no built-in handling. But `var yyyy= new Date().getFullYear(), Q1Start = yyyy+"-01-01", Q1End=yyyy+"-01-31", Q2Start =yyyy+"-04-01", Q2End yyyy+"-07-31"` and so on

Comment: The start and end dates you've given for `"quarter 1"` define just a single month (January), not a quarter.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ask if there is built-in functionality to get the startdate and enddate for each quarter and i will append the year field value to it.

Those are constants. Given your example for Q1, you're talking about the normal calendar quarters of a year. Q1 starts on 01/01 and ends on 31/03, Q2 starts on 01/04 and ends on 30/06, etc. Since no quarter starts or ends on the last day of February, this is not a moving target.

No, there's no built-in functionality, but you don't need any. Just construct dates from those constant month and day values and the year you need.

```
var q1 = {
    start: new Date(2017, 0, 1),    // Remember, January = 0 here
    end:   new Date(2017, 2, 31)
};
// ...
```

Or for UTC:

```
var q1 = {
    start: new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1)),
    end:   new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 2, 31))
};
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Quarter of a financial year starts on April 1 for many countries, so I would argue that you need to set the start of `quarter 1` first.

Let's say

```
var startDate = new Date();
date.setMonth(2);
date.setDate(1);
```

Then you can have functions like

```
function addQuarter(date) 
{ 
   date.setMonth( date.getMonth() + 3 ); 
   return date; 
}
```

For example

```
addQuarter(date); //returns Thu Jun 01 2017
```

Similarly to get last date of quarter

```
function lastDateOfQuarter( date )
{
  date.setMonth( date.getMonth() + 3 ); 
  date.setDate( date.getDate() - 1);
  return date;
}
```

You can format the date as per your requirements for display

```
function formatDate( date )
{
  return date.getDate() + "-" + ( date.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//if you are using current year 
var todayDate=new Date();

var startMonth=todayDate.getMonth();
var startDay=1;

var endMonth=todayDate.getMonth();
var endtDay=31;

switch(quarterValue){
  case "Q1" : startMonth=0;endMonth=2;
  case "Q2" : startMonth=3;endMonth=5;
  case "Q3" : startMonth=6;endMonth=8;
  case "Q4" : startMonth=9;endMonth=11;

}

todayDate.setMonth(startMonth);
todayDate.setDate(startDay);

var startDate=todayDate;

todayDate.setMonth(endMonth);
todayDate.setDate(endDay);

var endDate=todayDate;
```